# I am querying data from an api but useffect renders twice so i cannot fetch the information

Tags: reactjs, api, rest

i successfully fetch data from an api but i cannot map through it because on the app first render the data array is empty then an error of **data.map is not a function ** is displayed

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [names, setNames] = useState('')

 useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=kampala&appid=09da4ff6a7a9e25ddaa36518f64dc694`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => setData(response));
  }, []);

  console.log(data);

data.map(dt=>setName(dt.name))
```

Comment: Then probably, your response is not an array. In fact, it's an object, if I look at the response for the object, maybe you are more interested in the `data.weather` property?

Comment: how do i acces the data in the object for example the name, timezone, coorfinates or the weather help me understand that